# Can I cast Clinging Ice twice on the same target?

Tags: spellcasting, pathfinder-2e, cantrips, witch

[Clinging Ice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=793) is a Witch cantrip. It does very good damage for its action cost, but the "*target becomes immune for 1 minute after the spell ends*". The spell *ends* if you do not [Sustain](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=73) it at the end of your next turn, or after 1 minute if you do.

So if I cast it in the next turn, the target is not immune *yet*, and takes the damage. Right?
<s>(Or I could use it 6 times, 3 times per turn, but it is not *that* good)</s> Now that I think about it, it is *that* good, especially with Elemental Betrayal, but a [Hex](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=324) can only be cast once per turn.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, but it won't do much

[Sustain rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=291) say:

> If the spell’s duration is “sustained,” it lasts **until the end of your next turn** unless you use a Sustain a Spell action on that turn to extend the duration of that spell.

Clinging Ice has a duration of ***Duration** sustained up to 1 minute*
and says:

> Once this spell ends, the target becomes temporarily immune for 1 minute.

If you don't sustain the spell, it will last until the end of your next turn. During that next turn, it has not ended yet, so the target is not immune yet.

However, there is the [general rule](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312) on Duplicate Effects:

> **Duplicate Effects**
> When you’re affected **by the same thing multiple times, only one instance applies**, using the higher level of the effects, or the newer effect if the two are the same level. For example, if you were using mage armor and then cast it again, you’d still benefit from only one casting of that spell. **Casting a spell again on the same target might get you a better duration or effect if it were cast at a higher level the second time, but otherwise doing so gives you no advantage.**

So, yes the target is not immune, but your second casting will still do nothing beyond dealing damage, as only one instance of the spell applies. Since they still become immune after the first intance ends at the end of the turn, you won't get the sustain effects of the second casting, and no more damage after that for the next minute:

> If you have immunity to a specific condition or type of effect, you can't be affected by that condition or any effect of that type.

Comment: You may want to clarify that the second casting will still do damage, so it's not entirely nothing.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical, the damage is the _point_. This would be a pretty good cantrip even if it did nothing _but_ damage. It does better single target damage than any other cantrip in 2 actions from level 3.